# How to get self advertising address in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Because BLE MAC address rotating after android 5, so my question is how to get my self advertising address?

Comment: you want to get your own Bluetooth mac address, right?

Comment: @Vladyslav yes, I want the address in my advertising packet.

Comment: if your device is advertising mac address, then you simply need to make connection and read that specific characteristics.